# Choosing a name for an open source library

Tags: language-agnostic, open-source, naming

How important it is that a Google search for the name will return no result?

If the library is written in Java and a search for 'java *libname*' returns 10,000s results, does it mean you should try harder and find a name that's availble?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming as defined in the [help].

Answer (score 3):

It's popularly said: if you can't be found in google, you don't exist.

- Jeff Atwood: [If It's Not in Google, Does Your Website Really Exist?](https://blog.codinghorror.com/if-its-not-in-google-does-your-website-really-exist/)
- Jeff Atwood: [... if every other search engine in the world shut down tomorrow, our website's traffic would be effectively unchanged...](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-elephant-in-the-room-google-monoculture/)
- Rob Watson: [Without Google you don't exist](https://ion.icaew.com/itcounts/b/weblog/posts/withoutgoogleyoudontexist)
- Bob Pearson, VP Communities & Conversations, Dell: [... The corporate homepage, dell.com, that's not the real homepage. The real homepage is Google...](http://www.web-strategist.com/blog/2008/11/25/video-interview-how-dell-is-benefitting-from-social-media/)
- JavaLobby: [On any given day over 10,000 visitors arrive at Javalobby as a result of Google searches, and suddenly they stopped coming!... Suddenly we no longer existed in the eyes of Google, the world's largest search engine](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t87997.html)
- Reputation Defender Blog: [$400 million mall doesn't exist, because Google doesn't know about it](https://www.reputationdefender.com/blog/general/if-youre-not-google-you-dont-exist)

So while your name doesn't have to be absolutely unique, it does have to be distinctive enough for you to be found on Google...

Answer (score 3):

That's not a very good criteria as Google will return all documents containing the word Java and your suggested name. Unless your name is a completely new word, it has likely been mentioned in the same document as the word Java at some point!

To have your project name rise to the top of Google, the important things are:

- Pick a word that isn't too common - it doesn't need to be unique, but it needs to be a word that people aren't using on every single web page in the world.
- Make sure it is prominent on all pages of your website, including in the title.
- Get lots of people to link to your site (of course this is the tricky bit!) Open Source projects have a much better chance of getting to the top of Google for their name than websites on many other topics, simple because geeks generate a lot of links, esp. to sites hosting good, free, software.